# How to disable Babel in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js

Simple question, I know, but googling has turned up nothing. I've recently been sold on simply omitting Babel transpilation in my projects. I don't have any business need to pander to pre-ES6 era browsers in this day and age!

How do I remove babel from my Nuxt project? Is it as simple as setting `babel: false` somewhere? My package.json is loaded with countless '@babel' packages, I'd love to find a clean way to just remove everything Babel-related.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this option may help: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#ignore

So, you could probably try this as explained in the [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#babel):

```js
export default {
  ...
  build: {
    babel: {
      babelrc: './.babelrc',
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

And into your `.babelrc` file, you may write

```js
{
  "ignore": [
    "**/*"
  ]
}
```

Didn't tried it myself but it may be a working idea.

Answer (score 0):

I set

```js
build: {
    babel: {
      babelrc: false,
    },
}
```